# Dropdown menu to radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, button, drop-down-menu, smarty

I have a dropdown menu on a search section. When I select something from the dropdown menu the search fields are changing. I want to transform the dropdown menu to radio buttons.
Here is the code of the dropdown menu :

```
    <select id="qs_category" name="qs_category" onchange="onQuickSearch(this.form, '{$live_site}'); {if $multi_depending}reloadDep('{$multi_depending}', '{$live_site}');{/if}">
            <option value="">{$lng.search.all_categories}</option>
            {foreach from=$categories item=v name=cat}
            <option value="{$v.id}"{if $v.parent} class="opt_parent"{/if}{* {if $cat==$v.id && $self_noext=="listings"}selected="selected"{/if}*}>{$v.str}{$v.name|escape:"html"}</option>
            {/foreach}
    </select>
```

Can someone help me to transform this into radio buttons ?

Comment: You shouldn't ask someone to do the work for you like this.

Comment: I want to know how to do it and I will do it myself. I just dont know how.

Comment: pls add javascript tag and others if required.

Answer (score 1):

To transform this to radio buttons, you can just use `<input type="radio"...`

```
<label>
    <input name="qs_category" type="radio" value=""
           onclick="onQuickSearch(this.form, '{$live_site}'); {if $multi_depending}reloadDep('{$multi_depending}', '{$live_site}');{/if}">{$lng.search.all_categories}
</label><br>
{foreach from=$categories item=v name=cat}
<label>
    <input name="qs_category" type="radio" value="{$v.id}"{if $v.parent} class="opt_parent"{/if}{* {if $cat==$v.id && $self_noext=="listings"}checked="checked"{/if}*}
           onclick="onQuickSearch(this.form, '{$live_site}'); {if $multi_depending}reloadDep('{$multi_depending}', '{$live_site}');{/if}">{$v.str}{$v.name|escape:"html"}
</label><br>
{/foreach}
```

The duplicated `onclick` isn't quite elegant but this is the most straight forward way for you to understand.

To make the codes look better, you can bind the `onclick` event with Javascript. If you are using jQuery, it will be

```
$('input[name=qs_category]').click(function() {
    onQuickSearch($(this).parent(), '{$live_site}');
    {if $multi_depending}
        reloadDep('{$multi_depending}', '{$live_site}');
    {/if}
});
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your quick reply. The code is working partially. The dropdown menu has changed into radio buttons, but when I select one of the buttons the search fields are not changing accordingly. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Okay, I forgot to change onchange to onclick, this should work.

Comment: Could you please help to solve this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595547/convert-dropdown-to-selection-boxes-with-color